# How to create in XPages a submit button to discard the current and create a new document?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I need to create a link on a XPage to refresh the panel with a new document. 
The current document must not be saved.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a link with the URL to the page where this link is on, e.g.

```
<xp:link text="Discard and start over" value="/thepage.xsp?action=newDocument"></xp:link>
```

Comment: Thanks!
What if it is a custom control, and I don't know the xpage?

Comment: You can compute the page name via Serverside Script e. g.  view.getPageName()

Comment: Works good!
It would be cool to do the same without a full refresh. 
But anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure I totally get this but I don't see the need for a full refresh.  it might help if you showed code.  But you should be able to refresh a panel / repeat control without needing a full refresh.  Sometimes you do need to trigger a refresh in the onComplete property to get something like this working.  I don't know the why's or reasons for that though.  It seems to me like xpages just beats the view update...

Answer (score 0):

you can reinstatiate a data source bound to a panel using the following code. Try running that before you submit.

var c = getComponent("mypanel");
var ds = c.getData();
ds.get(0).refresh();